# Render settings are not applying

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

Why i have 40 Path Tracing with low render setting?
It seems like the render settings i make are not applying anymore.
What can i do solve this? I want to regain my old render settings with 1 Path Tracing.

[image]

Comment: I see, i confused samples with path tracing tiles x.x
That explains why the regular render viewport, 
shows me just 1 sample to render an preview.... 
Good, this takes alot of stress from me, thought i did something wrong and ruined the entire project.
Thanks for answer!

Comment: Is it possible to make "samples" visible in the "render view" window?
I would like to have/get more information when a render process is ongoing.

Comment: For newer questions please ask on a new post.

Answer (score 0):

What you are seeing is 40 tiles to be rendered. In the posted image the computer was rendering the 23th tile out of 40